# Some systems not attempting to register IPv6 reverse

Tags: windows, ipv6, ddns

I have a few Windows 2012 systems in my domain that are not dynamically updating their records in the `ip6.arpa` zone for their assigned IPv6 addresses.

I have systems that are publishing their record just fine.  So I am pretty confident that the problem isn't on the DNS server side.

On the systems that are not working I have verified with Wireshark, and Windows is not sending the Dynamic DNS update for the `ip6.arpa` zone after running `ipconfig /registerdns`, but an update is sent and acknowledged as successfully for the IPv4 reverse zone, and the domains forward zone.

I am looking for reasons why systems would not be attempting to register their IPv6 address.

The systems have a valid working IPv6 address and can access IPv6 resources on the Internet.  The `Register this connection's address in DNS` box is checked.  From what I can see through the GUI, the same settings exist for working, a system that is working and not working.

[image: ipv6 dns settings]

Comment: You've _manually_ configured an IPv6 address on this server. Do the ones that work _also_ have manually configured IPv6 addresses?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, yup.  At the moment all my servers are statically configured.  And most of them are correctly registering their IPv6 PTR records.

Comment: Well, something is different between them. Are they all Hyper-V servers, like this one?

Comment: This is a Hyper-V guest, not server,  I have other Hyper-V guests that are working.  I agree something must be different, though I have no idea what.  This particular VM is brand new, I just installed it this morning from the Windows 2012 R2 media.  It is in the same OU (same GPOs) as working systems, as far as I can tell there are no differences.  But I suspect I am not looking in the right place.

Comment: You mentioned that this is a new install from R2 media. Have you applied all patches since the R2 media was created? There may be an update that fixes this, as this does seem to be a bug.

Comment: Yes, they are fully updated.